# Difference between using Trace and TraceSource

Tags: .net, logging, system.diagnostics, tracesource

Anyone knows the difference between `System.Diagnostic.Trace` and `System.Diagnostic.TraceSource` classes?

I've been using Trace for most of my projects and I just happen to found out about `TraceSource` the other day. They seems to offer similar API, is one better than the other?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

TraceSource is the newer version (since .NET 2) and Trace is the older version, more info is available here:

[Clarification on TraceSource/Trace](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/3b05b16e-a566-4909-8e37-f3d8999d5977)

Comment: From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228989.aspx: "TraceSource is intended to function as an enhanced tracing system and can be used in place of the static methods of the older Trace  and Debug  tracing classes. The familiar Trace  and Debug  classes still exist, but the recommended practice is to use the TraceSource  class for tracing."

Comment: This article could be very helpful too.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2005/03/15/396431.aspx

Answer (score 10):

TraceSource allows you to enhance the granularity over your tracing : in your config file you can enable/disable only the tracesource you want at the level you want (information, warning, error, ...)
You can find really good explanation here : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/149251/Debugging-Tracing-and-Instrumentation-in-NET-and-A