# Is it possible to get a live STREAM of an Azure Work Role Trace?

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles, trace, diagnostics

Scott Hanselman has a [great post about streaming an azure -web- role to your console](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/StreamingDiagnosticsTraceLoggingFromTheAzureCommandLinePlusGlimpse.aspx). Love it.

I'm really struggling to figure out how to do this with a **WORKER** role. Even more distressing is that I'm trying to do this with the newer TraceSource stuff, not the older Trace stuff .. and nothing is working.

Does anyone have any ideas if

1. Can this even be done (as of the time of posting this)
2. If so, some instructions on this, please?

Extra reading:
1. [Difference between using Trace and TraceSource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101174/difference-between-using-trace-and-tracesource) 
2. [A Tracing Primer](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2005/03/15/396431.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

Scott Hanselman is demonstrating streaming the log for a [Windows Azure Web Sites](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/services/web-sites/) site NOT a Windows Azure (PaaS) [cloud service](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/services/cloud-services/) web role. You can use Windows Azure Diagnostics to capture and persist logs to Windows Azure Blob Storage - and I don't believe there is a built-in way to stream them from there.